# How Do I unnest following structure of json into interpretable table using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have dataframe  `df`  which has column called  `test_col`  which contains json structures as shown below. As you can see lineItemPromotions object has nested jsons in it which can have 0-10 numbers of items in it. By unnesting, it should create new rows for each ID under lineItemPromotions.
How do I unnest this structures correctly?

```
{'provider': 'ABC',
 'discountCodes_out': [],
 'discounts_out': [],
 'lineItemPromotions': [{'id': '1',
   'discountCodes': [],
   'discounts': [{'rule': 'Bundle Discount',
     'name': 'Bundle Discount',
     'ruleId': '',
     'campaignId': '419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9',
     'centAmount': 1733550}],
   'perUnitPromotionsShares': [1733550]},
  {'id': '2',
   'discountCodes': [],
   'discounts': [{'rule': 'Bundle Discount',
     'name': 'Bundle Discount',
     'ruleId': '',
     'campaignId': '419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9',
     'centAmount': 119438}],
   'perUnitPromotionsShares': [119438, 119438]}]}
```

I tried following code but it is not working correctly. It is giving me nested item which I have to unnest again. Sorry that I have to paste the picture to show you the process how it is giving results.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pd.json_normalize(new_dict, meta='provider', record_path='lineItemPromotions')`?

Comment: yes, but it gives dataframe which has nested columns for discounts, kinda want to unnest everything in that json objet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although verbose, you could explicitly normalize each level:

```
pd.concat(
   [
      pd.json_normalize(data).explode("lineItemPromotions")
        .drop(columns="lineItemPromotions").reset_index(drop=True),
      pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["lineItemPromotions"])
         .drop(columns="discounts"),
      pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["lineItemPromotions", "discounts"])
   ], 
   axis=1
)
```

```
  provider discountCodes_out discounts_out id discountCodes perUnitPromotionsShares             rule             name ruleId                            campaignId  centAmount
0      ABC                []            []  1            []               [1733550]  Bundle Discount  Bundle Discount         419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9     1733550
1      ABC                []            []  2            []        [119438, 119438]  Bundle Discount  Bundle Discount         419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9      119438
```

You could then `.explode("perUnitPromotionsShares")` if desired.

Comment: this is also works fine to some extent, but only problem remains with 'discountCodes_out'  column which again has list of jsons in it. e.g. [{'code': 'WELCOME71', 'rule': '', 'name': ...

any idea on how to modify your code in order to unnest that column to on same granularity?

Comment: It depends on what exactly `discountCodes_out` looks like and what output you want. It would help to include it in your example.

Comment: so in some case discount code is None, in some case it is empty list and most of the cases it is a dictionary like this only : ```[{'code': 'WELCOME39571',
   'rule': '',
   'name': '',
   'ruleId': 'ef95038f',
   'campaignId': '0e88b060',
   'centAmount': 1377}]```

Comment: You'll probably have to show an exact example of the output you expect in the case of that dictionary input. I've added in a custom function I use which you can try and see if that's the output you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You could first explode your columns then concat with a new df made from the `discounts` column:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(new_dict, meta='provider', record_path='lineItemPromotions')
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
pd.concat([df.drop(columns='discounts').reset_index(drop=True), 
           pd.DataFrame(df['discounts'].values.tolist())], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  id discountCodes perUnitPromotionsShares provider             rule             name ruleId                            campaignId  centAmount
0  1           NaN                 1733550      ABC  Bundle Discount  Bundle Discount         419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9     1733550
1  2           NaN                  119438      ABC  Bundle Discount  Bundle Discount         419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9      119438
2  2           NaN                  119438      ABC  Bundle Discount  Bundle Discount         419f9a2f-0342-41c0-ac79-419d1023aaa9      119438
```

Comment: thanks, I know I can drop duplicates from result dataframe but do you know why are we getting 2nd and 3rd row exact same?

Comment: and also is there way to have discountCodes_out and discounts_out in same dataframe output? thats the most imp thing I am struggling with.

Comment: It occurs while exploding `perUnitPromotionsShares`. you can choose to explode `discounts` only instead: `df = df.explode('discounts')`

Comment: You can specify other meta values in a list: `meta=['provider', 'discountCodes_out', 'discounts_out']`. However the empty lists in your exemple will cause problems

Comment: Thanks, will try it. So few of the rows have it as empty but other rows have important info in 'discountCodes_out', 'discounts_out'.

Comment: I was using some other methods too including solution you jussgested in your comments, which would end up giving following error: ```ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (2)   ```            Is there any way around this from your experience, cause I tried lot of solution from ChatGPT too, but could not resolve this error after including ```'discountCodes_out', 'discounts_out'.``` because although there are few records which are having empty values for  ```'discountCodes_out', 'discounts_out'.```, rest have useful info in this fields.

Comment: You could fix your dictionary directly, for instance: `if new_dict['discounts_out'] == []: new_dict['discounts_out']=None`

Comment: thanks, I guess fixing json is easier than any other solution